# OnFocus and OnBlur is not working for lightning-input in Lightning web components (LWC)

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, js

Aim: To call a js method when an lightning input text is filled in LWC form. Eg: After typing Salesforce and moving out the field should invoke the JS function.

```
<lightning-input label="Email" type="email" required onchange={onUserEmailChnage}></lightning-input>
```

By using lightning-input's onchange function, JS function is being called after typing each and every alphabet like s, sa etc are sending to JS function instead of sending Salesforce.

```
<lightning-input label="Email" type="email" required onblur={onUserEmailChnage}></lightning-input>
```

When I use 'onfocus' or 'onblur' instead of 'onchange' getting an Error as attached.[image: OnBlur/OnFoucs]

Can anyone help me on building a functionality which should call JS function when complete word is typed.

Comment: Is the handler function name correct : onUserEmailChnage or is it onUserEmailChange ? You have interchanged few letters.

Answer (score 2):

Tried above scenario on lightning [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/example) and it works fine.

Markup code :

```
<lightning-input type="email" label="Email address" required onblur={onUserEmailChnage}></lightning-input>
```

js code :

```
onUserEmailChnage(event) {
        console.log('input value ',event.target.value);
    }
```

onBlur will fire when user focus moves away from the input element which should be correct given the use case.

Comment: Thank you. I have used event.detail.value on js which is reason for the error.

Comment: Please mark it as the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

onblur and onchange also don't fire on aura cmp, if the type is email. Works well if type is not stated which means string.